# setvalues to nested formgroup from the JSON object angular 10

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular-reactive-forms

I do have JSON object coming from backend and would like to set values for it in better way. What are the best approach I should consider?

I do know to manually set values to objects based on the key param.

Is there any other optimized way I can do this?

```js
//backend response
"response": {

    "senderCode": "123",
    "senderName": "test2",
    "receiverCode": "456",
    "name": "test",
    "contactnumber": "1233333333"

}
//formgroup structure

this.Form = this.fb.group({
    receiverCompanyCode: null,
    // Sender Information
    senderInformation: this.fb.group({
        senderCompanyCode: [null],
        senderName: [null],
    }),

    // Contact Information
    contactInformation: this.fb.group({
        name: [null, Validators.required],
        telephone: [null, Validators.required],
    }),
});
```

Answer (score 2):

may be this help you

```
const response = {
      name: 'test',
      telephone: '1233333333'
};
this.contactInformation.setValue(response);
```

Answer (score 2):

you have to manually map the data into form value

```
const mappedValue = {
receiverCompanyCode: response.receiverCompanyCode,
    senderInformation: {
        senderCompanyCode: response.senderCompanyCode,
        senderName: response.senderName,
    },
    contactInformation: {
        name: response.name,
        telephone: response.telephone,
    }
}
this.Form.patchValue(mappedValue);
```

or change the FormGroup structure and patch response value directly

```
this.Form = this.fb.group({
    senderCode: [null],
    senderName: [null],
    receiverCode: [null],
    name: [null],
    contactnumber: [null]
});
this.Form.patchValue(response);
```